# Dealing with pixels in contours (OpenCV)?

Tags: c++, algorithm, opencv

I have retrieved a contour from an image and want to specifically work on the pixels in the contour. I need to find the sum (not area) of the pixel values in the contour. OpenCV only supports rectangle shaped ROI, so I have no idea how to do this. cvSum also only accepts complete images and doesn't have a mask option, so I am a bit lost on how to proceed. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to find the sum of the values of pixels in a specific contour?

Comment: What's the contour representation? Pixel coordinates? Image/mask? Why can't you just loop over the pixels?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't really understand the question. The contour consists of a sequence of points that surround a specific area. I don't see how I can just loop through the pixels. The contour can be any shape - anything from a contour of a human body to one of a dog - the lack of a fixed shape mean's I can't really "loop"

Comment: If the contour's pixels are given as coordinates in some array, you loop over that array, take coordinates out of it and then look at the image pixel with those coordinates. If the contour is in an image and its pixels have a specific color (or range) that distinguishes them from everything else, just loop over the image pixels and look at their colors to see if they're the contour pixels. If you don't have the coordinates and there's no specific color range for the contour pixels, it's a different kind of problem, it's harder. You didn't specify the representation. That's why I asked about it

Comment: Your right, Ill try to make my question less vague next time. I do not however have the coordinates and there isn't any specific colour range for the pixels. I think I found a solution to the problem, but it would be EXTREMELY slow. I basically use cvCopy to transfer each contour's contents to a new image and then find the sum of that image. This would give me the sum of each contour's pixel values but going through each contour one by one would be very slow. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: And I forgot to mention: my application works in real time, therefore solutions require a high degree of speed.

Comment: What exactly is a "contour" here, you use that word like it doesn't have like a million interpretations.  You have arbitrary shapes, with arbitrary pixel colours, placed in arbitrary locations on an image? And you want to find and compute the sum of the pixels of the edges? Clearly there is not going to be a tractable or even correct algorithm for this...

But you say you can split up the contours, so what exactly are your inputs here? You have the individual images? In what form? do you know where the edges are? are they convex shapes? are they continuous?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First get all of your contours.  Use this information to create a binary image with the white parts being the contour's outline and area. Perform an AND operation on the two images. The result will be the contours and area on a black background. Then just sum all of the pixels in this image.

Comment: First of all, what you are suggesting will give me the sum of ALL the contours. I want each sum separately not totally. Secondly, as I said in my question, I don't want to calculate the area of the contour but instead the value of pixels already non-black in the contour. Your method will make all pixels in the contour white, completely defying the point of the application.

Comment: when you AND the binary image and the original image, what you get is an isolated image.  You will not get an all white image.  If you want one at a time, you can create the binary mask and AND the two images one at a time.

Comment: sorry if i did not explain myself well.  But i have done a similar thing myself with success.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand right you want to sum all the pixel intensities from a gray image that are inside a contour. If so, the method that i think of is to draw that contour on a blank image and fill it , in so making yourself a mask. After that to optimize the process you can also compute the bounding rect of the contour with :

```
CvRect cvBoundingRect(CvArr* points, int update=0 );
```

After this you can make an intermediate image with :

```
void cvAddS(const CvArr* src, CvScalar value, CvArr* dst, const CvArr* mask=NULL);
```

using the value 0, the mask obtained from the contour and setting before as ROI the bounding rect.

After this, a sum on the resulting image will be a little faster.

Comment: Thank You. From what I understand, you are basically isolating the contours contents, by using a mask. I see how it works, but I don't really understand the purpose of the bounding rectangle. If the contour's contents have been isolated, what's the point of having an ROI?

Comment: The point is to work on a smaller region when computing the sum or any other operation that involves going trough every pixel in an image.

Answer (score 0):

To access the contour's point individually follow the code

```
vector<vector<Point> > contours;
...
printf("\n Contours pixels \n");
for(int a=0; a< contours.size(); a++)
{  
   printf("\nThe contour NO = %d  size = %d \n",a, contours[a].size() );
   for( int b = 0; b < contours[a].size();  b++ )  
   {  
       printf(" [%d, %d] ",contours[a][b].x, contours[a][b].y ); 
   }
}
```

Comment: This will only result in the Points along the edges of the contour. Not the pixels inside.