# Comic Balloon Detection: How can I count white pixels inside a vector<RotatedRect> Ellipse in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, feature-detection, feature-extraction

I've been looking everywhere I can for the answer but I can't find one.

I'm making a comic balloon detection program and I need to find an ellipse that have a specific percentage of white inside the contour (percentage is to be decided later), thus why I need to count the white pixels inside the contour and I don't know how.

I have tried `countNonZero()` but since the parameter of that is an array it doesn't accept my `minEllipse[i]` or `contours[i]` that are declared as `vector<RotatedRect>`.

Below is the code:

```
// Modified version of thresold_callback function 
// from http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/bounding_rotated_ellipses/bounding_rotated_ellipses.html
            Mat fittingEllipse(int, void*, Mat inputImage)
            {
                Mat threshold_output;
                vector<vector<Point> > contours;
                vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
                int numberOfCaptions = 0;

                // Detect edges using Threshold
                threshold(inputImage, threshold_output, 224, 250, THRESH_BINARY);

                findContours(inputImage, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));

                vector<RotatedRect> minEllipse(contours.size());
                Mat drawing = Mat::zeros(inputImage.size(), CV_8UC3);

                for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
                {
                    if (contours[i].size() > 5)
                        minEllipse[i] = fitEllipse(Mat(contours[i]));
                }

                int totalContourSize = 0, whitepixels, blackpixels;

                //Draw ellipse/caption
                for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
                {
                    Scalar color = Scalar(255, 0, 0);

                    if (minEllipse[i].size.height >= inputImage.rows / 8 && //IJIP-290-libre.pdf
                        minEllipse[i].size.width >= inputImage.cols / 10 && //IJIP-290-libre.pdf
                        minEllipse[i].size.height < inputImage.rows / 3  &&
                        minEllipse[i].size.width < inputImage.cols / 3 &&
                        (
                        (minEllipse[i].angle >= 0 && minEllipse[i].angle <= 10) ||
                        (minEllipse[i].angle >= 80 && minEllipse[i].angle <= 100) ||
                        (minEllipse[i].angle >= 170 && minEllipse[i].angle <= 190) ||
                        (minEllipse[i].angle >= 260 && minEllipse[i].angle <= 280) ||
                        (minEllipse[i].angle >= 350 && minEllipse[i].angle <= 360)
                        )) {

                        ellipse(drawing, minEllipse[i], color, -1, 8);
                    }
                }

                drawing = binarizeImage(drawing);
                return drawing;
            } // end of fittingEllipse


            Mat CaptionDetection(Mat inputImage){
                Mat outputImage, binaryImage, captionDetectImage;

                binaryImage = captionDetectImage = binarizeImage(inputImage);
                threshold(captionDetectImage, captionDetectImage, 224, 250, 0); //IJIP-290-libre.pdf

                GaussianBlur(captionDetectImage, captionDetectImage, Size(9, 9), 0, 0);
                captionDetectImage = fittingEllipse(0, 0, captionDetectImage);

                //binaryImage = invertImage(binaryImage);

                outputImage = inputImage;

                for (int i = 0; i < inputImage.rows; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < inputImage.cols; j++) {
                        if (captionDetectImage.at<uchar>(i, j) == 0) {
                            outputImage.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[0] = outputImage.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[1] = outputImage.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[2] = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }

                return outputImage;
            } // end of CaptionDetection
```

The very bulky if statement yields me only 53% accuracy of getting the comic balloon detection (not to mention all the false detections), that's why I need to get the percentage of white pixels in the contours that are found to get a higher percentage.

**EDIT:**

My desired output would be the whole **manga page** would be black except the comic balloons and then count the number of white and black pixels there

**ONLY** on the `CaptionDetection` function should I count the number of pixels for each captions

**FINAL ANSWER**

I edited the code that user Kornel gave

```
            Mat fittingEllipse(int, void*, Mat inputImage)
            {
                Mat outputImage;
                vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
                int numberOfCaptions = 0;

                // Detect edges using Threshold
                threshold(inputImage, inputImage, 224, 250, THRESH_BINARY);

                findContours(inputImage, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));

                vector<RotatedRect> minEllipse(contours.size());

                for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
                {
                    if (contours[i].size() > 5)
                        minEllipse[i] = fitEllipse(Mat(contours[i]));
                }

                //Draw ellipse/caption
                outputImage = Mat::zeros(inputImage.size(), CV_8UC3);
                for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
                {
                    Scalar color = Scalar(255, 255, 255);
                    Mat drawing = Mat::zeros(inputImage.size(), CV_8UC3);

                    ellipse(drawing, minEllipse[i], color, -1, 8);

                    drawing = binarizeImage(drawing);
                    int area = countNonZero(drawing);

                    if ((area >= 10000 && area <= 40000) &&
                        (
                        (minEllipse[i].angle >= 0 && minEllipse[i].angle <= 10) ||
                        (minEllipse[i].angle >= 80 && minEllipse[i].angle <= 100) ||
                        (minEllipse[i].angle >= 170 && minEllipse[i].angle <= 190) ||
                        (minEllipse[i].angle >= 260 && minEllipse[i].angle <= 280) ||
                        (minEllipse[i].angle >= 350 && minEllipse[i].angle <= 360)
                        )){
                        ellipse(outputImage, minEllipse[i], color, -1, 8);
                        captionMask[captionCount] = drawing;
                        captionCount++;
                    }
                }

                imwrite((string)SAVE_FILE_DEST + "out.jpg", outputImage);

                return outputImage;
            } // end of fittingEllipse
            Mat replaceROIWithOrigImage(Mat inputImg, Mat mask, int k){
                Mat outputImage = inputImg;
                Mat maskImg = mask;
                imwrite((string)SAVE_FILE_DEST + "inputbefore[" + to_string(k) + "].jpg", inputImg);
                for (int i = 0; i < inputImg.rows; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < inputImg.cols; j++) {

                        if (maskImg.at<uchar>(i, j) == 0) {
                            inputImg.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[0] = inputImg.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[1] = inputImg.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[2] = 0;
                        }

                    }
                }
                imwrite((string)SAVE_FILE_DEST + "maskafter[" + to_string(k) + "].jpg", inputImg);
                return inputImg;
            }

            Mat CaptionDetection(Mat inputImage){
                Mat outputImage, binaryImage, captionDetectImage;

                binaryImage = captionDetectImage = binarizeImage(inputImage);
                threshold(captionDetectImage, captionDetectImage, 224, 250, 0); //IJIP-290-libre.pdf

                GaussianBlur(captionDetectImage, captionDetectImage, Size(9, 9), 0, 0);
                captionDetectImage = fittingEllipse(0, 0, captionDetectImage);

                for (int i = 0; i < captionCount; i++){

                    Mat replacedImg = replaceROIWithOrigImage(inputImage.clone(), captionMask[i], i);

                    int area = countNonZero(binarizeImage(replacedImg));

                    cout << area << endl;
                }

                return outputImage;
            } // end of CaptionDetection
```

The if condition in `fittingEllipse()` is to be edited for better accuracy later.

**Thank you for your help and time user a-Jays and Kornel!**

Comment: Once you have a contour, find your non-zero pixels _inside_ that contour.

Comment: @a-Jays Sorry but that is my problem, I don't know how to find it inside the contour.

Comment: Use a mask of the shape of your contour on your image, then find non-zero pixels in the new masked image. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8145036/dealing-with-pixels-in-contours-opencv

Comment: @a-Jays but by doing that I will only get like one plain white ellipse, I need to detect ellipse that have characters in the middle then count the white pixels

Comment: If you could post images it would be helpful. Otherwise, I don't see why having text in between would affect the outermost contour.

Comment: @a-Jays I don't have enough reputation to post images, sorry

Comment: I'm admittedly still far from understanding your problem, but one suggestion- you don't have to loop over all the pixels to apply a mask. You can use `sourceImg.copyTo( destImage, maskImg )`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you have a rotated rectangle `rRect` which defines an ellipse just like `minEllipse[i]` in your code.

First of all, the area of it can be estimated by the closed formula `area = a * b * PI`, where `a` and `b` are the semi-major and semi-minor axes (1⁄2 of the ellipse's major and minor axes), respectively, so:

```
cv::RotatedRect rRect(cv::Point2f(100.0f, 100.0f), cv::Size2f(100.0f, 50.0f), 30.0f);
float area = (rRect.size.width / 2.0f) * (rRect.size.height / 2.0f) * M_PI;
```

Or a bit shorter:

```
float area = (rRect.size.area() / 4.0f) * M_PI;
```

---

Alternatively, you can simply draw it over a mask by [`cv::ellipse()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#ellipse), i.e.:

```
cv::Mat mask = cv::Mat::zeros(200, 200, CV_8UC1);
cv::ellipse(mask, rRect, cv::Scalar::all(255), -1);
```

And you count the non-zero elements as the usual:

```
int area = cv::countNonZero(mask);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply but how can I count the white pixels in the contour?

Comment: By contour, I mean the manga in image inside the contour ( am I making sense?) I don't have enough reputation to post pictures, sorry :'(

Comment: Can you draw the most outer contours? You should add an external link to your images at least to clarify the problem.

Comment: I manage to edit the code you gave to count all the white pixels for the caption detection, thank you very much :)